# XSLT matches : Syntax error at char 0 in regular expression: No expression before quantifier

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a function with regex below, to find out match between input string and values.

```
<xsl:if test="matches($plantId,'136')">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="matches($itemGroup,'/^(C010|C040|C050|C060|C210|C320|C340|C390|T220|T240|T250|T260|T270|T290)$/s')">
            <xsl:value-of select="$itemGroup"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>FilteredOut</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```

But it get back the error in the subject.
Do you know why?
Thanks.
Marco.

Comment: I guess you want `matches($itemGroup,'^(C010|C040|C050|C060|C210|C320|C340|C390|T220|T240|T250|T260|T270|T290)$')`. Otherwise you need to explain what you expect the regular expression to match or why you used certain characters in there.

Comment: It also helps telling us exactly which software you use that gives that error.

Comment: Yes I mean compare $ItemGroup with "C010 or C040 or ..." values. If match found, function get back $ItemGroup value otherwise "FilterOut".
Application is XSLT translator of Infor ION. Tkx

Comment: Can be an alternative function to do the same ?

Comment: I think the function `matches` is fine and the approapriate arguments would be `matches($itemGroup,'^(C010|C040|C050|C060|C210|C320|C340|C390|T220|T240|T250|T260|T270|T290)$')`, I don't know what the leading `/` and the trailing `/s` are supposed to do, looks more like JavaScript regular expression syntax. I don't know which XSLT processor your tool uses

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex is valid, but will never match anything - `^` can only match at the beginning, it can't match after "/". I don't think you should be getting an error here, despite the fact that your regex is clearly wrong.